# Is there a way to use Coffeescript in Backbone.js templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using the `backbone-rails` gem to generate Backbone scaffolding for my Rails project.  This has generally been a positive experience, but templating is one area that could use a lot more refinement.

My Backbone code all uses Coffeescript and the only time I use vanilla Javascript now is when I need to test something in the browser [1] and when I want to insert Javascript into a template.  Semicolons and missing parentheses slow me down a lot, as I have to reload the browser each time I forgot one--which is often since my brain is in Coffeescript mode.

Is there a way to use Coffeescript in Backbone.js templates?

[1] sometimes I use Coffeescript with Firebug + Acebug, but the idea/task I'm testing has to be big enough, as it takes a few more mouse clicks to get through this process.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco).

Comment: +1. And maybe also at Brunch, which bundles Backbone and jQuery and eco and Coffeescript and a build script.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I took a look at this and it looks like it works mainly for Node.js.  I'm serving up Backbone templates from a Rails server and they're rendered client side.  It looks like Eco works server side only (unless I'm mistaken)